# npm scripts pass dynamic arguments from one script to the other

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

How can I pass arguments from one script to the other
using `npm-run-all` (to run in parallel)

```
scripts:{
   "start":"run-p dev watch -- --theme=$themeId",
   "dev": "webpack",
   "watch": "theme watch --env=$themeId"
}
```

Then calling start like:

`npm run start theme=2233`

But it wouldn't pass the argument to the `watch` argument

Answer (score 0):

Using `${npm_config_themeId}`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "run-p dev watch",
    "watch": "theme watch --env=${npm_config_theme}",
  }
```

Then calling
npm run start -theme=123